# get the value of the selected option in Typescript

Tags: typescript, dom

I am trying to get the value of the selected option in Typescript without Angular. I have set up the HTML as follows:

```html
<div class="formCol">
    <div class="form-group mt-5 mx-1">
    <select class="form-control" id="firstPoints1">
        <option name="point2" value="coner">coner</option>
        <option name="point2" value="edgePillar">edgePillar</option>
        <option name="point2" value="edge">edge</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

the associated javascript:

```
<script>
    let el = document.querySelector("#firstPoints1");
    let arr : Array <string>;
    function getSelected (el : HTMLFormElement, arr : Array <string>) {
        for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            if (el[i].selected) {
                arr.push(el[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
    function getSelected (el, arr)
```

But the following error occurs:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that it cannot do a **push** to an undefined element, you should try to initialize the variable **arr**, like:

```
let arr : Array <string> = [];
```